# Rewrite Rule in .htaccess file not working for subdomain to main domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

Essentially, my company I work for has a site that hosts pages for several different stores.  Each store has its own subdomain rule in cpanel so that users can enter a simple url from a flyer to get to the site for their local store.  Recently though, Bing has started indexing one of our subdomains which causes a bit of confusion for our customers since the link appears as https://[citystate].example.com/find-us/altstate/altcity

I've looked through several files and have gotten to this point where, from what I've seen, should work but doesn't.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[citystate]\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example\.com\/$1 [L]
```

Can someone please assist in where i'm going wrong?

UPDATE: The piece above is working but the URL is being redirected to the index page because the page is coming up as if it doesn't exist.  However, If I take the link and open it up in a separate browser window/tab it pulls up.  Color me confused.

Comment: Okay.  So I have found that I need this piece in order to capture the site and alter it's direction.

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[citystate]\.example\.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example\.com/$1 [L]

However, the ending portion of the URL is dropped and the site defaults to the index page.  Is there a way to pass over the URL chunk that comes after example.com/[all of this]?

Edit: attempted to format the comment for readability

Comment: Please edit your question to include this additional information. Unless the code is correctly formatted special characters are missing and it's hard to read.

Comment: @MrWhite, updated the rewrite condition and rewrite rule.

Comment: "the ending portion of the URL is dropped and the site defaults to the index page" - Your updated code sample already does this. Maybe you have a conflict with other directives in your `.htaccess` file? Please include the contents of your `.htaccess` file in you question, with these directives in place.

Comment: @MrWhite, you were right.  The rewrite condition set for when a file is not found was reverting it to the index page.  Now what doesn't make sense is that the URL works, but it's failing to pull up the page if redirected in this fashion.  (FROM) https://example.com/find-us/state (TO) https://example.com/find-us/state If I pull up the site with this link, it works, but not through the redirect.

Comment: That would seem to be the same URL? Presumably you don't literally have `[citystate]` in your regex, as otherwise that matches just a single character from the character class? This is an external redirect (although the `R` flag is missing), so there's no reason (without seeing the code) why this is not working as intended.

Comment: @MrWhite, What is it that you mean by a missing R flag?  Would the (.*) not reference the entire string correctly after the domain due to being a single piece; I'm not sure what you mean by the regex comment.

Comment: I've written an "answer" to add explanation and a more complete solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[citystate]\.example\.com
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example\.com\/$1 [L]
> ```

This rule needs to go near the top of your `.htaccess` file in order to avoid conflicts with other directives.

However, there's a couple of potential issues:

- The regex snippet `[citystate]` matches just a single character in the character class. `[` and `]` denotes the character class. So this matches either `c`, `i`, `t`, `y`, `s`, `t`, `a` or `e` - one character only. You need to specify the word literally, without the square brackets. However, if you have many "cities" then this requires a rule for each city, you could make the regex more generic to match any city. eg. `[a-z]+` (ie. 1 or more lowercase letters in the range `a` to `z`.)
- You are missing the `R` (`redirect`) flag on the `RewriteRule`. eg. `[R,L]` or `[R=301,L]`. However, since you have specified a scheme + hostname on the target URL, it will implicitly trigger a 302 (temporary) redirect - which is OK. However, in order to resolve the issue with Bing, this needs to be a 301 (permanent) redirect. But, do test with 302 (temporary) redirects first in order to avoid potential caching issues.

Minor issues:

- `^(.*)$` - regex is greedy by default, so the `^` and `$` (start and end-of-string) anchors are superfluous.
- There is no need to backslash escape literal dots and slashes in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* since this is an "ordinary" string, not a regex.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[a-z]+\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If the URL-path is not being captured properly by the `$1` backreference then you can use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable instead. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[a-z]+\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Note that the `REQUEST_URI` server variable contains a slash prefix, so this is omitted from the *substitution* string.

Comment: you're the man!
It turns out that I needed to add the piece at a higher point in the file like you mentioned and it works brilliantly.  Solved